# Typescript: How to sort complex strings by comparing the date inside

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list of 2 strings with date inside them, how can I sort it to let earlier one always comes to the first? The date is always after the second comma.

For example,

```
const example =
["AAA,5,2020-09-17T21:14:09.0545516Z",
"AAA,0,2020-09-03T20:38:08.3946643Z"]

sortStrings(example: string[]) {
  // how to sort to let earlier date come first
}
```

Comment: Please show your code or attempts in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const example = ["AAA,5,2020-09-17T21:14:09.0545516Z", "AAA,0,2020-09-03T20:38:08.3946643Z"]
example.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.split(",")[2]).getTime() - new Date(b.split(",")[2]).getTime())
console.dir(example);
```

Watch out, this isn't nearly optimized any only a quick example how you could short your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
sortStrings(example: string[]){
    example.sort((a, b) => {
        var aData = a.split(",");
        var bData = b.split(",");
        var aDate = new Date(aData[aData.length - 1]);
        var bDate = new Date(abData[bData.length - 1]);
        return (aDate > bDate ? 1 : aDate < bDate ? -1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question the terms `ascending` and `descending` become very significant. So here is an example:

```js
const example = ["AAA,5,2020-09-17T21:14:09.0545516Z",
  "AAA,0,2020-09-03T20:38:08.3946643Z"
]

function desc(a, b) {
  a = a.split(",").pop();
  b = b.split(",").pop();
  let aDate = new Date(a);
  let bDate = new Date(b);
  if (aDate.getTime() > bDate.getTime()) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (aDate.getTime() < bDate.getTime()) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

function asc(a, b) {
  a = a.split(",").pop();
  b = b.split(",").pop();
  let aDate = new Date(a);
  let bDate = new Date(b);
  if (aDate.getTime() < bDate.getTime()) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (aDate.getTime() > bDate.getTime()) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
example.sort(desc);
console.log(example);
example.sort(asc);
console.log(example);
```